# LaTeX tikz-timing - adjust fontsize independently for each row label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

I would like to be able to make the label below (which I have made red) have text size equivalent to `\tiny` but I can not figure out how to do it? I have not been able to find anyone else trying to change the label text size with `tikz-timing`; is it a PGF or tikz problem?

What is the syntax? 
I fear this is going to be an obvious misunderstanding of LaTeX, PGF, TikZ, and `tikz-timing`. I am a little confused which syntax to use when setting the style of the label.

I don't want to apply the changes to all labels as discussed in the following question: [How can I change the font family in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots?lq=1)

## Here is what I am starting with:

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock 128\,MHz 0\degr    & H   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  \color{red} Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr   & [C] 12{2C} C \\ % starts with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 180\degr  & C   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 270\degr  &     12{2C} C \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

## Attempted variations that do not work

```
  \color{red} Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr   & [C] 12{2C} C
  \color{red} \tiny Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr   & [C] 12{2C} C
  \color{red} \tiny{Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr}   & [C] 12{2C} C
  \tikzset{every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize}}
      \color{red} Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr}   & [C] 12{2C} C
  \color{red} [font=\sffamily\footnotesize}] Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr}   & [C] 12{2C} C 
  \tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.3}}
      \color{red} Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr}   & [C] 12{2C} C
```

## Edit

The following code is what breaks, I am trying to make it a standalone document class; type article works as you observed.

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=10pt]{standalone} %breaks on \tiny
  % Error|line 15|!Undefined sequence.<argument> \tinyClock\tiny Clock & [C] 12{2C} C\\
%\documentclass{article} % works with \tiny
%
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
% 
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock & H   12{2C} G \\
  \tiny Clock  & [C] 12{2C} C \\
  Clock & C   12{2C} G \\
  Clock &     12{2C} C \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always add a full, compilable but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, not just a code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please always post a complete, compilable but minimal example document which produces the issue you have. Code snippets are usually not very useful.

Usually simply adding `\tiny` should do the trick. The following minimal example works fine for me. I think some other setting in your document causes the problem. Create a copy and minimise your document in order to localise your problem. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for further details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\newcommand{\degr}{degr}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock 128\,MHz 0\degr    & H   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  \color{red}\tiny Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr   & [C] 12{2C} C \\ % starts with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 180\degr  & C   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 270\degr  &     12{2C} C \\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Update

The `minimal` class you are using doesn't define `\tiny` at all. Note that `minimal` isn't a real class, just a really minimal set required to get a LaTeX document compiled. Please see the posts [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class) for more details. There are some which consider `minimal` a good choice for `standalone` document ([What is the advantage of using minimal over article when creating a standalone graphic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-minimal-over-article-when-creating-a-standalone-g)), but I had my good reason to use `article` as default class for it (I'm the author of `standalone`, and also `tikz-timing`). Simply do not use the `minimal` class. It's not intended for minimal documents or example and will cause problems with otherwise normal macros. See [Why does the following code not compile? (tikz and scope)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76099/why-does-the-following-code-not-compile-tikz-and-scope) for a further example of such problems.

Comment: Hi Martin, I updated my post with breaking code in response to you. I am not sure if my original question was the correct location to add my edit. Thanks for your quick reply by the way; i was actually hoping you would answer since you are the genius behind tikz_timing :)

Comment: @DanielKing: Updating you original question was the correct thing to do. Just keep questions in a general tone so that there are more useful for other people, e.g. done refer directly to other users. Please also always post the error messages you get if you get some. The fact that you get an `Undefined sequence \tiny` error is a dead giveaway, for example.

Comment: Thanks for all the references on using minimal; I will definitely read them. In my actual application, I have a much larger document where I use \includegraphics pointing to my standalone figures in both the tex (discussed above) and pdf formats depending on where the figure is generated.